# How can one run user-defined commands in the "run command prompt" in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line

I have user-defined commands in my .bashrc-file, some of which I would I like to run without opening a terminal; By pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, I can bring up the "run command prompt" (as shown in the included image),

Image of what the "run command prompt" looks like. By default, the shortcut in Ubuntu 20.04 to bring the prompt up is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>:

[image: Screenshot 1]

but I whenever I run a user-defined command, such as my command "ds4" (declared in the .bashrc-file) to connect to my bluetooth controller, the prompt does not recognize the command (shown in second image), saying "Command not found".

Image of command not being recognized in command prompt:

[image: Screenshot 2]

I would imagine there is some file other than .bashrc, where the prompt can run user-defined commands from.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit your question and add how exactly you added user-definied commands in `.bashrc`. A more common way would be to write a little script in the language of your choice, make it executable and put the script in a directory that's in your path. Those scripts should be executable from the command prompt.

Comment: Does `ds4` work on a normal command line? You should be able to alt-t having added `| exit` to your command to get the same functionality. However there must be something stopping the “run command prompt” working.

Comment: Please copy-paste text and not screenshots (firewalls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to create a script in `~/.local/bin` (or in `/usr/local/bin` if the command should be available for all users on the system).

You then name the script `ds4`, and add the commands you want to run, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash

command 1
command 2
etc
```

And make the script executable: `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/ds4`.

Now you can run the command `ds4` from everywhere with your custom commands.

This may take a little more effort than simply making aliases, but the solution is completely platform independent, and will give you access to your custom commands everywhere (including across multiple desktop environments).